# When does a browser allow a user to interact with the web page

Tags: javascript, multithreading, events, handler

I have a web page which loads a number of scripts in the head section of the page. Some of these register "load" event handlers. It appears that users are able to interact with the web page before ALL load event handlers have completed.

Is this possible? I thought JavaScript was single threaded and no user interaction with a web page would be possible until the web page was fully loaded and all "load" event handlers had completed.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. The `load` event won't be triggered until all content has been loaded and parsed, including images, and you can definitely interact with the page before the images have finished loading. You may be looking for [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) instead.

Comment: Sounds like "load" might be the wrong event to be using.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, the issue with a third party library ibox.js, I have marked certain links with rel="ibox" which it then registers event handlers on (using the "onload" event). But it appears my users can click those links before ibox.js has had a change to fully run the event handler.

Comment: @thedoctor, then a possible workaround would be to neuter the links (possibly with a full-page transparent overlay) until `load` is triggered.

Comment: What is causing the page to load so slowly in the first place?

Comment: @epascarello we use a number of Win7/IE8 vm's for testing and the issue is most apparent there. Although it has been randomly (very infrequently) observed on normal desktops. It looks like the whole approach of using "onload" and attributes on tags is broken, as it's pretty random as to whether the user can interact with the tag before the additional event handlers have been registered.